# Show that G has an element g of p-power order with $\varphi$(g)=h

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\varphi$ map G to H be surjective homomorphism with G finite. Suppose h is in H has an order that is a power of the prime p. Show that G has an element g of p-power order with $\varphi$(g)=h.

Since it is surjective, I know we can decide to choose x such that $\varphi$(x) =h.
I am unsure how to prove this from here.

Comment: $\varphi(g^n)=\varphi^n(g)=h^n$. Proceed from here

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe but how do we argue that n is prime?